# AWS S3 ls profile does find user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am getting an error from aws cli on my Ubuntu desktop when running the command `aws s3 ls --profile=55667788-its-user`. When I run this command as my Ubuntu user it says it cannot find the config for the user, and if I swap to root I get access denied on s3 buckets.

Now, I ran aws configure and I set my profile in credentials and I also ran aws configure --profile as well, and I checked the config file. There's also an interesting problem that AWS_PROFILE is never found.

I am really banging my head as to why this is not working.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an .aws directory in your home directory (i.e. in ~/.aws).

Then, you will need a `config` file in which you will have your profile like:

```
[profile 55667788-its-user]
region = <YOUR PREFERRED SESSION> (e.g: eu-central-1)
output = json
```

You also need a `credentials` file with the following:

```
[55667788-its-user]
aws_access_key_id=<ACCES KEY GOES HERE>
aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET KEY GOES HERE>
aws_session_token=<THIS IS OPTIONAL, ONLY USE IT IF YOU USE SSO AND TEMPORARY SESSIONS>
```

The following should then work in your terminal:

```sh
aws s3 ls --profile 55667788-its-user
```

Comment: Not sure you read post. This what I have done but it falls to work

Answer (score 0):

Check `credentials` file. I assume you have several profiles in it. When I created my second profile, `aws configure` didn't add new line. So, it looked like this:

```
[default]
...
region=us-west-2[55667788-its-user]
aws_access_key_id=...
```

which caused all kind of problems.
Also, check the permissions - it has to be 600 (no read for group or other)